# Binomial probability large n, very small probabilty

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I'm trying to compare binomial & poisson probability results but I'm struggling to get decent results from binomial method. 
So the n is about 10,000 & the probability is 0.0005 (5 successes out of 10,000). Is there a way I can get decent values using binomial method?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by decent values?

Comment: If you're trying to calculate probabilities for a binomial with $n=10000,p=0.0005$, you can do it directly or do a Poisson approximation. A normal approximation will give bad results in this regime. On a computer it might in fact be problematic to try to do the binomial calculation because of floating point issues.

Comment: Arka, I meant reasonable values, similar to poisson results

Comment: Can you explain a bit of what problems you encounter when you try to do a direct binomial calculation?

Comment: For example, do you encounter difficulty with accurately computing things like $0.9995^{10000}$? If so, note that it is the same to have $\exp(10000 \ln(0.9995))=\exp \left ( 10000 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} (0.0005)^n \right )$. The Poisson approximation for $P(X=0)$ takes just one term of this sum, but you can take more, and it converges quite fast.

Comment: Ian, the poisson approximation results are good but I need to compare the results with binomial. My conclusion is the binomial results are completely wrong. For eg: for zero success, poisson = 0.67%. For Binomial, its 98.6%.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, there is some serious calculation error going on. Here the binomial probability of zero successes is ${10000 \choose 0} 0.0005^0 (0.9995)^{10000}=0.9995^{10000}$ which is just a tiny bit bigger than $\exp(-5)$ (around 0.1% bigger), which is the Poisson value.

Comment: (By the way, if you want to ensure a response, you need to use @, as in "@Ian". I only noticed this because I was checking back over my recent comments.)

Comment: @Ian True Ian. But once x =1, 2 etc, the results becomes very small.

Comment: @NathanPanggabean Could you be forgetting to multiply by the binomial coefficient? For instance with $x=1$ you have ${10000 \choose 1} 0.0005^1 0.9995^{9999}=5 \cdot 0.9995^{9999}$ which is again just slightly larger than the Poisson value.

Comment: @Ian Thanks Ian, that seems to clear it up. The spreadsheet I made seems to only respond to lower n's & higher probabilities. I'll change it to suit. Thank you very much!